# Simulate logistic distribution with continuous variables

Tags: r

The intention involves finding the causal relations of breakdown (0,1) for a washing machine. The commands for the logistic distribution created randomized variables except for the dependent variable which are all 1. The simulation from the other logistic distribution created randomized 0 and 1 values.

Variables, Hrs2, WashCap, and SpinSp created as normal distributions with n=3000. I altered the mean and SD for fitting the desired interval on the x-axis of the histogram.

```
# Hours2
set.seed(600)
Hrs2 <- rnorm(3000, mean=300, sd=100)

#WashCap
set.seed(5)
WashCap <- rnorm(3000, mean=2.5, sd=1)

#SpinSp
set.seed(1100)
SpinSp <- rnorm(3000, mean=550, sd=250)
```

The difference for the logistic distribution includes an additional variable for the linear combination with a bias.

```
z=1 + 2*Hrs2 + 3*WashCap + 4*SpinSp

pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))

y <- rbinom(3000,1,pr)

WashMa = data.frame(y=y, Hrs2=Hrs2, WashCap=WashCap, SpinSp=SpinSp)

glm( y~Hrs2+WashCap+SpinSp,data=WashMa, family=binomial)
```

Any thoughts for fixing the dependent variable to create variation?

Comment: It seems that the parameters are currently chosen so that failure is so highly probable that `y` shows little variation; consider e.g. transforming the `z` parameters to modify the simulated failure rate (e.g. to approximately 50% of cases using `z. <- (z-mean(z))/sd(z); pr. = 1/(1+exp(-z.)); y. <- rbinom(n,1,pr.); table(y.)`).

Comment: Please cross-link this question and the several answers you received in stackexchange.

Comment: @texb Simulating the failure rate to 50% with z. <- (z-mean(z))/sd(z created variation for y.                                              > table(y)
y
   0    1 
1497 1503

Comment: @user28272: So is that as you intended, or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @texb Yes the simulation works as expected now. Thanks for your help.